# EnupalSnapShot don't work

Tags: php, plugin-enupalpdf

I recently updated my plugin license (enupalsnapshot), and it turns out that now it doesn't want to work anymore. I use the option to generate PDF from the URL and it returns the following error in the logs:

```
2021-08-27 21:28:02 [-][-][-][error][enupal\snapshot\Snapshot::error] Something went wrong when creating the PDF file: The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:
stderr: "Loading pages (1/6)
[>                                                           ] 0%
[===>                                                        ] 5%
[======>                                                     ] 10%
Warning: Blocked access to file                                   
[=======>                                                    ] 12%
[===================>                                        ] 32%
[==================================>                         ] 57%
Error: Failed to load about:blank, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol "about" is unknown
[============================================================] 100%
[======>                                                     ] 10% 
[==============================>                             ] 50%
[============================================================] 100%
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
[=>                                                          ] 2%
[===>                                                        ] 5%
[====>                                                       ] 7%
[======>                                                     ] 10%
Warning: Blocked access to file                                   
[======>                                                     ] 11%
[============>                                               ] 21%
[===================>                                        ] 33%
[=========================>                                  ] 43%
[=================================>                          ] 56%
[=======================================>                    ] 66%
[==============================================>             ] 78%
Error: Failed to load about:blank, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol "about" is unknown
[============================================================] 100%
Printing pages (6/6)                                               
[>                                                           ] Preparing
[==============================>                             ] Page 1 of 2
[============================================================] Page 2 of 2
Done                                                                      
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ProtocolUnknownError
"
stdout: ""
command: "/home/bancodecelulas/wkhtmltopdf" --lowquality --dpi '96' --load-error-handling 'ignore' --zoom '1.33' --footer-html '/home/bancodecelulas/storage/runtime/temp/enupalsnapshottemp/knp_snappy61298311c8aec5.94627450.html' --header-html '/home/bancodecelulas/storage/runtime/temp/enupalsnapshottemp/knp_snappy61298311c8b111.33836819.html' '/home/bancodecelulas/storage/runtime/temp/enupalsnapshottemp/knp_snappy61298311c8a970.20658900.html' '/home/bancodecelulas/storage/runtime/temp/enupalsnapshottemp/public/HGC-27.pdf'.
2021-08-27 21:28:01 [-][-][-][info][application] $_GET = [
    'p' => 'celula/0310'
]
```

Comment: Seems as one of the referenced templates is not accessible? "Warning: Blocked access to file "

Comment: But I just updated the plugin key and it happens to me. How can you?